# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'homePage'

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to go to the home page after login button is clicked, but I keep getting the error :

`Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'homePage'`

This are my routes:

```
{
  path: 'homePage',
  component: HomePageComponent,
  outlet:'homePage'
},
{ 
  path: 'login',
  component:LoginComponent
},  
{ 
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/login',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

And this is the button to be clicked:

```
<button routerLink="homePage" id="login" md-button>Log in</button>
<router-outlet name="homePage"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the router to route inside your named outlet like this:

```
<button [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ homePage: ['homePage']} }]">
  Edit
</button>
```

More about routing with named outlets can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets).

---

As stated by me in the comments of this answer, it sounds like you just want to have a simple unnamed router outlet.

Make sure you have only one outlet inside your app component's template:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And then remove the outlet property from your route:

```
{
    path: 'homePage',
    component: HomePageComponent
}
```

And for the router link just use

```
<button routerLink="/homePage></button>
```

Comment: Ok, now it shows the home page but the login form won't go away.

Comment: Sure because your `login` route is the default route (you're redirecting to it). Are you sure that you want to use named router outlets ? For me it sounds like you just want to have a unnamed router outlet.

Comment: @annie It stays because you created new router outlet for homePage. In your case you should have only one router-outlet inside your app.component.html. So this answer is correct, but you want to achieve something else. You should understand how routing and named outlets works.

Comment: Ok, I'm not using named outlet anymore, but the login form still won't go away

Comment: Did you removed the outlet option from your routes definition and make sure you just have one `<router-outlet>` inside your app component's template ?

Comment: Actually I don't have a component named `app`, instead I have `login`. And I have the outlet in the login template where  the login form is

Comment: Your applications root component should be some kind of app component, because your login is just a component which is displayed on a specific route, not all the time. So you have to change your app structure to have some kind of app component as root which has an `<router-outlet>` inside its template.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<button routerLink="homePage">
```

to

```
<button routerLink="/homePage"
```

Comment: Trying using the name outlet method
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { homePage: ['homePage'] } }]